# How to rewriting URL with HTACCESS

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

This is a line of code on my htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ details.php
```

And this is working fine with this URL

```
example.com/shiv-sales-corporation
```

Now i want to add .html at the end of URL

```
example.com/shiv-sales-corporation.html
```

I have changed my htaccess code with this

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)\.html$ view_details.php
```

but the other pages or links are conflicting after it, kindly help me please!

Note: "shiv-sales-corporation" is a slug which i fetching it from the database, it changed randomly by other link on page. Examples:

```
example.com/ibm

example.com/apple-corp

example.com/himalaya-ltd
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work for you:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)([\.html]*)$ view_details.php
```

I am assuming that you want to redirect to view_details.php each time the URLs you listed are accesed. No matter if .html is present or not.

Comment: Yes but your code is still giving  the same issue. it's only configuring the .html and redirecting all the html link to details.php

Comment: Check here:
http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

It works here. You can also try this:

`RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)([\.html])*$ view_details.php`

Hope this tool will help :)

Comment: RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+)\/products\.html products.php         Now this kind of RewriteRule is not working, all the .html url going to view_details.php

Comment: Add this rule:
`RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)([products\.html]*)$ products.php`

Answer (score 0):

[Click to More](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/modrewrite-tips-tricks.html)

RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ $1 [R=301,L]

Answer (score -1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /details.php?name=$1 [L]
```

where name is your dynamic parameter coming from database

Comment: you cant give this name because its coming randomly from the database.